# jQuery set active/hover background images

Tags: jquery, css, events

I have a list that has 5 items in, the first one (on load) is active (with a class of 'active' added by jQuery). They all have background images associated with them. If I click any of the li's another div updates with relevant content (this is working).

However I'm struggling with the following:

If you click an li, update its background image to be colour (suffix of '-cl.png'). When I hover over another one, update its background image to be colour and keep the clicked one (with a class of 'active') colour too. If an li is not hovered over set the background image to be black and white (suffix of '-bw.png') but keep the active one colour.

Hope I've explained myself clearly. Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Thanks, Brett

Here's my HTML:

```
<ul class="graduate_tab">
<li class="graduate1"><a href="#grad1"><span class="gradimg1">grad1</span></a></li>
<li class="graduate2"><a href="#grad2"><span class="gradimg2">grad2</span></a></li>
<li class="graduate3"><a href="#grad3"><span class="gradimg3">grad3</span></a></li>
<li class="graduate4"><a href="#grad4"><span class="gradimg4">grad4</span></a></li>
<li class="graduate5"><a href="#grad5"><span class="gradimg5">grad5</span></a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would do *most* of the work in CSS, like this:

```
.graduate1 { background: url(image1-bw.png); }
.graduate1.active, .graduate1:hover { background: url(image1-cl.png); }
.graduate2 { background: url(image2-bw.png); }
.graduate2.active, .graduate2:hover { background: url(image2-cl.png); }
//etc...
```

Then in jQuery all you need to worry about is the `active` class, like this:

```
$('.graduate_tab li').click( function() {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Using [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) on the clicked one and [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) on the rest will move the `active` class to the clicked one...if you want to be able to remove it from an already active one (toggle it off) you can replace [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) with [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for that behavior.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.graduate_tab li').hover(
  function() { 
    $(this).css('background-image','your-image-cl.jpg'); 
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('background-image','your-image.jpg'); 
  });

$('.graduate_tab li').click( function() {
  $('.graduate_tab li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

This should do the trick. In case I forgot something, tell me, and I'll edit the code.

Comment: Squ36, thanks for the reply. That's not quite what I'm after. What I need to do it detect which li is hovered, set that one to colour, keep the 'clicked' one colour and set the rest to b&w. All the iamges are different but match the li naming convention eg. graduate1-bw.png, graduate2-cl.png etc.

Answer (score 2):

I used the click hover jquery function.  No need to give each `li` a class in css. Hence:

```
.ui-state-active, .ui-state-hover  {
    font-weight: bold !important;
    //and other css
}
```

and

```
 jQuery('.graduate_tab li').bind('click hover', function () {
        jQuery(this).addClass('.ui-state-active')
                    .siblings().removeClass('.ui-state-active');

 });
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 
:hover

property in css

active:hover {background-color:black;}

somthing like this...

but i am not sure it will work in ie6.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.titleclz').mouseenter(function( event ) {

    $(this).css('background-image','url(bg-image1.png path)');
    $(this).css('background-repeat','no-repeat'); 

});

$(".titleclz").mouseleave(function( event ) {

    $(this).css('background-image','url(bg-image2.png path)');
    $(this).css('background-repeat','no-repeat');

});
```

JQuery get image background hover effect...